# Is there a repository for html/css techniques?

Tags: html, css

I often end up searching my histoy and bookmarks for common css/html techniques such as [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) or [CCS3 Gradient Buttons](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons) and I can't but think if there is a proper repository that has them all?

Comment: The "50 awesome tips for HTML5 and CSS3" posts on design blogs are all over the place.  No way one place is gonna try and catalog all that stuff since there's so much of it out there.  Just Google "html5 css3 tips" for a deluge of what you are looking for.

Comment: How can you find a technique called "Sliding Doors" if you don't know it's called _sliding doors_ ? 
Sure Google is your friend, and Bookmarks your lover if I may... but sometimes a _directory_ is the best place to find things.

Answer (score 0):

A site that I have found many of these techniques on is [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/). The blogs are generally very thorough and provide good, working examples.

Comment: Durr it looks like you've found list apart as your first link is from them. But it is still one of the best I've found.

Comment: A List Apart is with no doubt an incredible place to find those kinds of things, but you still have to tell a part which are "techniques" well accepted and other kind of articles. 
Besides, although all the good techniques of ALA have become norm, not al norm techniques belong to ALA's site.